# Register usage and WASM compiler

Tags: assembly, compilation, webassembly, wasmtime

I am using Ubuntu on x86_64. I first generate non-optimized WebAssembly code from clang. The WebAssembly code is compiled into machine code using `wasmtime` which uses `cranelift` as compiling backend.

I am doing a simple matrix multiplication:

```
int first[m][n], second[p][q], multiply[m][q];
```

Here is the machine code for the first loop out of the three loops

```
for ( int c = 0 ; c < m ; c++ ){}
```

generated by `wasmtime`. I found many necessary instructions, but I cannot find a calling convention from cranelift to necessitate these instructions.

[image: Assembly code]

1. My questions are mainly around `esi` register, does the compiler has to use it for get `c`'s value using `esi`. Must `esi`'s value be preserved? Otherwise why not directly use it to do `cmp`. If yes, why in `1ad` we use esi to store 0 which is from `r14d` which is from `eax`? Also, the 0 value is preserved in `eax`, is eax also a non-volatile register?
2. In `1b0`, if we directly `cmp esi, r12d` and set esi 0 or 1 according to results, there is no need to complicated steps `1ba`-`1c3` Right?
3. If I generate optimized machine code from optimized WebAssembly using

   ```
    wasm32-wasi-clang -O2
   ```

   I dont think cranelift by itself provides an optimization flag though, I find the machine code much shorter but also hard to understand. Are there any ways to help me read optimized machine code? AND Also, if my machine code is from the non-optimized wasm. According to the analysis we just did on this for loop example, is it ok to say that I have found the flaws of wasm compiler, cranelift?

Thank you so much for your help! I know the code may not be enjoyable to read, you can zoom in the page to see the picture

```
  195: rex mov DWORD PTR [rbx+rdx*1+0xc],eax         ;int c = 0, eax preserves 0. 

  19a: rex mov edx,ecx                              ; edx = ecx = [rdi+0x60]  + 0xffffffc0  

  19d: rex mov esi,DWORD PTR [rbx+rdx*1+0xc]         ; esi = [0xc]  = c,  get c into register? 

  1a2: mov    r12d,DWORD PTR [rbx+rdx*1+0x38]       ; r12d = m 

  1a7: mov    r14d,eax               ;r14d = eax = 0         
  
  1aa: rex mov eax,esi               ;     eax = esi = [c] = c [[!!! abuse register, you can directly use esi for cmp, eax remains 0, instead of store eax value 0 in r14d, 
                                                        ;use eax for cmp, and at the end restore eax value 0 by esi (esi = r14d)]

  1ad: mov    esi,r14d               ; esi = r14d = 0;  

  1b0: cmp    eax,r12d               ; cmp if eax (c) < r12d (m), if yes, al = 1, otherwise al = 0; {can use esi?? cmp usage ?}

  1b3: setl   al               

  1b6: movzx  eax,al               ; eax = al = 1 (if <)   [movzx already uses zero-extension!!]

  1ba: and    eax,0x1              ; eax = 1 if (if <). [al is low 8 bits, set only supports one byte, Byte Set On Condition (setcc), why not directrly set r12d also has low 8 bit !!!! ]

  1bd: mov    r12d,eax             ; r12d = eax = 1 (if <)

  1c0: rex mov eax,esi                ;eax = esi =  r14d = 0;   [restore eax = 0, but why use esi rather than r14d, actually you dont even need to restore eax 
                                                        ;if choose to replace eax with another register in CMP   ]

  1c3: mov    esi,r12d             ; esi = r12d =  eax = 1 (if <) [!!if directly use esi for CMP, there is no need of mov 12d, eax then mov esi, r12d]

  1c6: rex test esi,esi ;if esi=0 jump

  1c9: je     2f0 <_wasm_function_3+0x227>
```

Comment: @NateEldredge Hi Nate, I am sorry. It is pasted now.

Comment: Yeah that asm has some pretty braindead stuff, like using `and eax, 1` on the result of `setl` which is already 0 or 1.  And using a useless REX prefix on a lot of 32-bit instructions that don't use any of R8..R15. (So there are missed optimizations even with the machine code for encoding a single instruction, separate from choosing which instructions to use.)

Comment: @PeterCordes Thank you! I dont know what does REX prefix do? Does it mean expand 32 bit insturction into 64 bit? While my code never uses higher 32 bit so it is not necessary? And the above code does not use R8...R15. Do they have a special purpose?

Comment: https://wiki.osdev.org/X86-64_Instruction_Encoding#REX_prefix.  Note the `0x40` REX prefixes with none of the low 4 bits set in some instructions, where the disassembly says `rex mov eax,esi` for example.  It means the REX prefix *didn't* change the meaning of the instruction, and is just wasting space in the machine code.

Comment: Thanks again. REX is only needed for 64bit operand correct? wasting space in the machine code: is registers space wasted or anything else? Would that affect execution performance?

Comment: REX is also needed for `mov  esi,r12d` to encode that it's r12d, not one of the 8 "legacy" registers.  Wasting code size means wasting I-cache footprint, so yes if your code is front-end bottlenecked it can limit performance, or make *other* parts of your code slower by evicting it when it didn't need to.  Also affects how it can pack into the uop cache.  See https://agner.org/optimize/ (especially his microarch PDF).  Also Intel's optimization manual, but it's really long.

Comment: Can i ask a bit more:) (1) `rex mov eax,0x0` I think this rex is not necessary, right? (2) I think you were trying to say if `R8d - R15d` appear in instructions, rex is also needed, right? (3) what if it is r12b, is rex still needed? (4) The microarch PDF is also very long but thank you. I know perf can measure `L1-icache-loads`   and `L1-icache-load-misses`, considering my matrix multiply code is small in size,  would rex causes any differences in the above two events? If no, can perf measure I-cache footprint directly?   (5) I dont know uop cache, Is it sufficient to use I-cache data only

Comment: Any instruction that decodes with `rex` in the text is indicating that the REX is there but not needed.  Almost *all* of them have `0x4?` REX prefixes, but some don't mention it because it's needed.  (3) try it yourself, assemble with NASM or GAS and look at the machine code to see the `0x4?` REX prefix.  (4) no, this loop would mostly hit in the uop cache (DSB in Intel perf counter terminology), so you'd see very few L1 icache loads.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229471/discussion-between-yeehaw-and-peter-cordes).